# How to check pods project into same repository as main project xcode 7?

Tags: git, github, xcode7, cocoapods

I am trying to add git to an existing xcode project. The project directory contains the actual project as well as the project generated by cocoapods. My directory looks like this.

```
MyProject
 - MyProject.xcworkspace
 - MyProject.xcodeproj
 - Other project files
 - podfile
 - .git
 - Pods
  - Alamofire etc
  - Pods.xcodeproj
  - .git
```

Xcode source control automatically creates a repo for both MyProject and Pods. I set the same remote repo for both projects. When I try to push to my remote repo, Pods is successfully pushed but Myproject fails with an error along the lines of failed to commit files, check if you have permission to do this. Obviously I have permission as Pods is working properly. I assume the problem is that I have the pods project inside of MyProject. I have tried manually deleting the repo for Pods and just pushing MyProject but it wont let me make any commits. What is the best way to handle this? Should I just forget about xcode source control and use the command line to manually create one repo for the whole directory? Is there somewhere better that I could keep my Pods project rather than inside MyProject? Can I force xcode to create only one repo? 
Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:
I went into xcode preferences and unchecked then rechecked enable source control. Now in the source control menu it only shows MyProject. I assume this is because MyProject already had a repo. Pushing now to see what happens. If the entire MyProject directory is added including Pods then I will call that a success however I believe that checking each project into separate repos is probably the better way to handle it.

UPDATE 2:
I have tried numerous ways of configuring it through xcode. I even tried to ignore the pods project but still couldn't get it to work so I willl be using the terminal instead.

Comment: Could you post the output of `git status` in `MyProject`? How about in `Pods`? In `MyProject`, what does `git ls-files Pods` output?

Comment: Keeping in mind that it is currently in the state where I have deleted the .git directory from Pods. For git status on Myproject it outputs:On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean. For Pods it outputs the same thing. The second command lists all the files in the pods directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I set the same remote repo for both projects.

This is your mistake, you should set separate repos. `MyProject` and `Pods` folders aren't "different version of the same folder", so they should not share a repo.

Also, to repair your current repo, try running these commands:

```
cd MyProject
git rm --cached Pods
echo Pods >> .gitignore
git add -A
git commit
```

Once you've done that, clone your `Pods` checkout again:

```
mv Pods /tmp/
git clone <path to remote Pods repo>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to check that I understand what you are saying. I should continue using xcode source control, just use separate repos(remote and local) for each project. I should also make the MyProject repo ignore pods as it is being checked in separately. Is this correct. Also, could I not just delete the repo instead of trying to repair it and start again?

Comment: Yeah, you have a correct understanding. You can delete the repo too if you want, I just wanted to give the "safest" solution. If I were you, I would forget about xcode source control and put everything on one repo; you'll get a better understanding of what's going on and stackoverflow be able to answer your questions more easily. But if you're fond of doing it inside xcode, go ahead, I've never used it and maybe it's quite nice.

Comment: I have a decent understanding of it without xcode as I have been using it for web projects. Just thought that It might make things easier with xcode. Probably not worth it in the end. Check my update to see my possible solution. If it doesn't work then i'll do as you said and stop using xcode sc.